# insert char with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a string '(abc)def(abc)' and I would like to turn it into '(a|b|c)def(a|b|c)'. I can do that by:

```
    word = '(abc)def(abc)'
    pattern = ''
    while index < len(word):
        if word[index] == '(':
            pattern += word[index]
            index += 1
            while word[index+1] != ')':
                pattern += word[index]+'|'
                index += 1
            pattern += word[index]
        else:
            pattern += word[index]
        index += 1
     print pattern
```

But I want to use regular expression to make it shorter. Can you show me how to insert char '|' between only characters that are inside the parentheses by regular expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z-][^)(]*\))', '|', '(abc)def(abc)')
'(a|b|c)def(a|b|c)'
```

- `(?<=[a-zA-Z])` Positive look behind. Ensures that the postion to insert is preceded by an alphabet.
- `(?=[a-zA-Z-][^)(]*\))` Postive look ahead. Ensures that the postion is followed by alphabet

  - `[^)(]*\)` ensures that the alphabet within the `()`
  - `[^)(]*` matches anything other than `(` or `)`
  - `\)` ensures that *anything other than `(` or `)`* is followed by `)`

    This part is crutial, as it does not match the part `def` since `def` does not end with `)`

Comment: I'm not good at regular expression. So can you explain what does your expression do?

Comment: @dragon2fly I have added an explanation. If you want more explanations feel free to drop a comment :)

Comment: is any search condition need to be inside the parentheses and the order of conditions must followed your?

Comment: @since there is nothing outside the lookbehind or lookahead paranthesis, its ok to write in any order, ie look ahead followed by look behind. But this is not a general case. it all depends on the string you need  to match. As of search conditions, this one liner would do your job. Tested in python2.7

Answer (score 1):

I dont have enough reputation to comment, but the regex you are looking for will look like this:

```
"(.*)"
```

For each string you find, insert the parentheses between each pair of characters.

let me explain each part of the regex:

```
( - *represends the character.*

. - A dot in regex represends any possible character.

\* - In regex, this sign represends zero to infinite appearances of the previous character.

) - *represends the character.*
```

This way, you are looking for any appearance of "()" with characters between them.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be `\(` and `\)`?

Comment: From my expirience,the normal "re" library normal "()"s work well. I`ll check it when I get home :)

Comment: @A.Abramov No that would make a group, you need to escape them

Answer (score 1):

```
([^(])(?=[^(]*\))(?!\))
```

Try this.Replace with `\1|`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/13

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'([^(])(?=[^(]*\))(?!\))')
test_str = "(abc)def(abc)"
subst = "\1|"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only single characters in your round brackets, then what you could do would be to simply replace the round brackets with square ones. So the initial regex will look like this: `(abc)def(abc)` and the final regex will look like so: `[abc]def[abc]`. From a functional perspective, `(a|b|c)` has the same meaning as `[abc]`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Python version to achieve the same thing. Regex is a bit hard to read and often hard to debug or change.

```
word = '(abc)def(abc)'
split_w = word.replace('(', ' ').replace(')', ' ').split()
split_w[0] = '|'.join( list(split_w[0]) )
split_w[2] = '|'.join( list(split_w[2]) )
print "(%s)%s(%s)" % tuple(split_w)
```

We split the given string into three parts, pipe-separate the first and the last part and join them back.

Comment: the word may vary from abcdef to (ab)cdef, ab(cd)ef, (ab)(cd)(ef)... so I need a regex to put the vertical bar in right places.